# Plotting 3D GIF in R

Tags: r, 3d, data-visualization, gif

I was working with 3 vectors `x` , `y` , `z` , each of length N (Assume N to be some large natural number, say 20000). In order to visualize this, I was able to plot this easily using the following R code :

```
library("plot3D")
lines3D(x, y, z, type = "l")
```

Now, I was thinking if we can make a little 3D animation (i.e. a 3D GIF) from the vectors `x` , `y` , `z`. Is it possible in R ?

---

**NOTE :** I've previously done 2D GIFs in R, with the help of packages like `ggplot2` , `gganimate` , `magick` etc. However, I'm curious whether the same thing can be done for 3D data. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I’m pretty sure that there are ‘rgl’-based animation opportunities but SO discourages questions where there’s no data and no efforts at searching. Also discouraged are package recommendations.

Answer (score 2):

It is very simple to create .gif with the `animation` package (note it requires ‘ImageMagick’ or ‘GraphicsMagick’ to run). After the installation, you could do something like this (I assume that you want to display your plot with different point of view):

```
library(plot3D)
library(animation)
x <- runif(1000)
y <- x*2+runif(1000)
z <- sample(1:10,length(x),replace = T)*x/y

ani.options(interval=0.5,nmax=35)
saveGIF(for(t in seq(0,360,10)){
lines3D(x, y, z, type = "l",theta=t)
}, movie.name = "animation.gif")
```